# How update an Activity on "onResume"?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I have a listview filled with some text. But when the listview is empty, it will show a button that takes you to a new activity, where you type some text and it saves on SharedPreferences and finishes. I want the Listview's Activity to update when the other one is closed. I tried onResume() but for some reason it stays refreshing forever. How do I do that?
By the way, I'm updating using:
`startActivity(getIntent());
finish();`
Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks.

EDIT-----------------------------------------------
As @Alex Loper said, I added `notifyDataSetOnChange()` in the `onResume()` method. But it crashed with this log:

```
12-31 19:45:05.284  11864-11864/com.nerv.cas.partying E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nerv.cas.partying, PID: 11864
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.nerv.cas.partying/com.nerv.cas.partying.YourPartiesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nerv.cas.partying.YourPartiesActivity.onResume(YourPartiesActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2845)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My class is like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_parties);

    user = getUserData();
    fillUserParty(user);
    fillAdapter(user);

    ListView partiesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.parties_list_view);
    Button goToCreatePartyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_create_party_button);
    if(adapter != null){
        partiesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        partiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        goToCreatePartyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        goToCreatePartyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(YourPartiesActivity.this, CreatePartyActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void fillAdapter(User user){
    List<Party> parties = user.getParties();
    if(parties != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parties.size(); i++) {
            Party party = parties.get(i);
            adapter.add(party.getName());
        }
    }
}

private void fillUserParty(User user){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Parties", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int numOfParties = CreatePartyActivity.checkNumberOfParties(preferences);
    for(int i=0; i<numOfParties; i++){
        String partyName = preferences.getString("Name" + i, "");
        if(partyName != ""){
            int id = preferences.getInt("Id" + i, 0);
            Party party = new Party(id, partyName);
            user.joinParty(party);
        }
    }
}

public User getUserData(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("User", 0);
    int id = preferences.getInt("Id", 0);
    String username = preferences.getString("Username", "");
    String name = preferences.getString("Name", "");
    return new User(id, username, name);
}
```

Comment: How you set ListView adapter?
onResume() is best way. Please add onResume code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find initialize adapter in posted code. I think adapter always is null!

To resolve null pointer exception, change onResume method like this :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (adapter != null)
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onResume()` call your listview adaptor's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to redraw the listview with the new information.

EDIT: Based on the posted code and stack trace, the adapter is never instantiated before it's used and is causing the NPE. Instantiate the adapter before calling `if(adapter != null){` so that it gets populated correctly.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_parties);

    ListView partiesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.parties_list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    user = getUserData();
    fillUserParty(user);
    fillAdapter(user);
    partiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button goToCreatePartyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_create_party_button);
    goToCreatePartyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    goToCreatePartyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(YourPartiesActivity.this, CreatePartyActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: When I add that method, in any place it crashes and says Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.

Comment: @Cas Post the full stack trace along with your code for initializing the listview, listview adapter, and the adapter code if you are using a custom adapter.

Comment: Just added the log and the full class.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the database and "contentprovider", you will be able to use Loaders(LoaderCallback) which will help in monitoring changes in the underlying datasource.

You will realise that when the second activity starts, the first activity calls onpause then after about 10 seconds calls ondestroy sometimes. So depending on onresume to manage states might be tight